# How to use a completion handler to put an image in a SwiftUI view

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5, completionhandler

I have tried this, but I didn't know how to use the results in a SwiftUI View:

```
func getProfilePicture(_ completion: @escaping ((UIImage) -> Void)) {

    Alamofire.request(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 75) ?? "https://httpbin.org/image/png").responseImage { response in

        if let image = response.result.value {
            completion(image)

        }
    }
}
```

If you can help, I would like to put the returned image from the completion handler in this view:

```
struct ProfileView: View {
let profileInfo = ProfileInfo()
var placeHolderImage = Image(systemName: "person")

var body: some View {
    Group {
            placeHolderImage
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .overlay(
                    Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
                .shadow(radius: 10)
                .padding(10)
    }

}

}
```

I would like this to return a UIImage so I can eventually use it in a SwiftUI view. I have already tried using a method with an @escaping completion handler, but I couldn't figure out how to use it to fix the issue. Thanks!

Comment: put a breakpoint at the line where you've got `return image`. What is it?

Comment: @Adrian What do you mean?

Comment: Have a peek at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgspBMsWlS4. Type. `po image` after you've thrown in a breakpoint and see what it is.

Comment: Also, have a peek at the section `struct ImageProvider: RequestImages` in this post. https://medium.com/better-programming/completion-handler-in-swift-4-2-671f12d33178

Comment: @Adrian I got this result: <UIImage:0x280950510 anonymous {37.5, 37.5}>

Comment: Cool...so you're getting what you need. Now just write the completion handler. The link I posted above should get you there. Kamran's answer should do the trick :)

Comment: @Adrian So I understand the completion handler, but how would I use it in the swiftUI view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201357/discussion-between-eli-front-and-adrian).

Comment: I think you should accept the answer and ask another question. You’ve expanded the scope of your original question. TBQH, I haven’t fiddled with SwiftUI much, so I don’t have an authoritative answer there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something let this:

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    @State var placeHolderImage = Image(systemName: "person")


    var body: some View {
        Group {
            placeHolderImage
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .overlay(
                    Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
                .shadow(radius: 10)
                .padding(10)
        }.onAppear{
            getProfilePicture{ image in
                self.placeHolderImage = Image(uiImage: image)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

When `ProfileView` appears it will call `getProfilePicture`. The `image`  specified in `image in` (when calling the function) is what the completion handler passes through (`completion(image)`). What you can then do is change your `placeHolderImage` to what you get in `getProfilePicture`, but before you do that you need to make your `uiImage` into an `Image`. Also make sure you add the `@State` keyword to your variable so once it changes your `View` is updated.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Use a completion handler as below,

```
func getProfilePicture(_ completion: @escaping ((UIImage) -> Void)) {

        Alamofire.request(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.currentUser.profile.imageURL(withDimension: 75) ?? "https://httpbin.org/image/png").responseImage { response in

            if let image = response.result.value {
                completion(image)

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this before, but I had a hard time using the completion result in a SwiftUI view

Comment: @EliFront I can't provide exact solution as i didn't use `SwiftUI` much as of now. But i think you will need some `State` variable and bind your `Image` to that and later once you get the `UIImage` in completion, just set `State` variable so your `Image` can update. You can check this [link](https://dev.to/gualtierofr/remote-images-in-swiftui-49jp) as well.

Comment: Too bad because I feel like I’m so close. I just need to figure out how to call a function from within a swiftUI view that doesn’t return a view

Answer (score 1):

```
import SwiftUI

@available(macCatalyst 14.0, *)
@available(iOS 14.0, *)

struct MyUIView : View {
    
    // MARK: - Properties -
    
    @StateObject var myStore : MyStore = MyStore()
    @State var imgArray : Array<Image> = Array<Image>.init(repeating: Image("no-image"), count: 100)

    // MARK: - View -

    var body : some View {
        
        ScrollView {
                                        
            Text("IMAGES")

            LazyVStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 8.0) {
                
                // actionPlans
                
                ForEach((0 ..< myStore.data.count).clamped(to: 0..<2), id: \.self) { i in
                    
                    HStack {
                        
                        let url = myStore.data[i]
                                       
                        let img : Image = imgArray[i]
                        
                        img
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .leading)
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0.0, bottom: 0, trailing: 16.0))
                            .onAppear(){
                            
                                imageFrom(url: url, completion: { image in
                                                                    
                                    imgArray[i] = Image(uiImage: image!)
                                                                            
                                })
                                
                            }
                                                    
                    }
                    
                    Divider()
                    
                }
                            
            }
                        
        }.onAppear(perform: {
            
            fetch()
            
        })
                
    }
    
    // MARK: - Media -

    private func fetch() {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
            myStore.getData()

        }

    }
    
    func imageFrom(url: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
        
        // image
                                
        if ImageLoader.sharedInstance.checkForImage(url: url as NSString?) {
            
            // has image
            
            completion(ImageLoader.sharedInstance.returnImage(url: url as NSString?)!)
            
        } else {
            
            ImageLoader.sharedInstance.getImage(url: url as NSString?) { (image) in
                                    
                if image != nil {
                    
                    completion(image)
                    
                } else {
                    
                    completion(UIImage.init(named: "no-image"))
                    
                }
                            
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}

@available(macCatalyst 14.0, *)
@available(iOS 14.0, *)

struct MyUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        MyUIView()
    }

}
```

Comment: I want you to know that your answer here finally made completion handlers click for me. Not sure why it was so hard for me to connect the pieces together but for some reason this example code put them all together. :)