# How can I get the result in the UI (@escaping , completion)

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I've got an func that read data from DB. this func with @escaping. how should I declare a var in UI, to get my result. thanks

```
class GetGarbageInfo {

    func getInfo(path: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        var result = ""
        
        let rootReference = Database.database().reference()
        let garbageReference = rootReference.child("GarbageInformation").child(path).child("body")
        
        garbageReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (DataSnapshot) in
            result = DataSnapshot.value as? String ?? "0"
        }
        completion(result)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
getInfo(path: yourPath) { resultString in 
   /// resultString is the result!
}
```

Comment: I've got this error in UI: Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Comment: Wait, you're calling this function in SwiftUI? Where? Is it inside a button's `action`?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58546001/14351818)

Comment: i try it but it don't work. but thank you for your support)

Comment: @LeonidSpiridonov here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/aheze/502a9438202f176d81216a6531f0e5a8), it should work

Answer (score 0):

With this code in works great. Thanks everyone for help)

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let garbageInfo = GetGarbageInfo() 
    
    @State var result = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(result)
        }.onAppear {
            garbageInfo.getInfo(path: yourPath) {
                result = resultString
            }
        }
    }
}




class GetGarbageInfo {

func getInfo(path: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    var result = ""
    let rootReference = Database.database().reference()
    let garbageReference = rootReference.child("GarbageInformation").child(realPath).child("body")
    
    garbageReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (DataSnapshot) in
        result = DataSnapshot.value as? String ?? "0"
        completion(result)
    }   
}

}
```